# Sierra Asks to Set Up Mac Each Boot

Tags: startup, macos

Since upgrading to Sierra, every reboot OSX asks me to set up Siri then says "setting up mac".

How do I stop this?  It seems to be blowing away my KeyRepeat settings in `NSGlobalDomain`

Answer (score 1):

Hold Control+Shift+Option and press the power button.  Release and power on normally.  This works... surprisingly